# How to set an icon in the listview?

Tags: android, image, listview, icons

Want to know how to set an icon in the default listview. I don't want to create a new custom listview but would want to just add an image as icon in the default listview. Is that possible? If yes then how?

Comment: It is possible, just create a custom XML layout, and create a custom adapter to inflate your layout and apply it to the listview object in your activity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could achieve adding a Image to the item of the listview. You will have to create the custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

To new a listview adapter and rebuild the item of the listview, and then white a layout xml file for the item, and relate it to the adapter.